# jQuery vertical news ticker plugin but controllable

Tags: jquery, news-ticker

I'm looking for a plugin for a vertical news ticker like this for an example:
http://www.jugbit.com/jquery/vticker.php

What I am trying to get is a plugin with controls like:

- stop
- start
- previous
- next

Can you help me out finding something similar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is something I wanted to find: http://buildinternet.com/2011/02/totem-a-vertical-ticker-jquery-plugin/